# How to grep text with brackets only

Tags: grep

the log looks like:

```
2019/10/04 03:03:12.938 [error]: some exception happened
2019/10/04 03:03:12.938 [error]: some exception happened
2019/10/04 03:53:35.595 [info]: there is a benign error in the code
```

grep "error" log.txt will give me all three lines but I only want the top two. How do I do that?

Comment: `grep "\[error\]" log.txt` can you try this?

Answer (score 1):

You may either grep all lines containing `[error]:`

```
grep '\[error]:' file
```

Or, you may use `awk` to check if the third field is equal to `[error]:`

```
awk '$3 == "[error]:"' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/SJJvaU)

```
#!/bin/bash
log="2019/10/04 03:03:12.938 [error]: some exception happened
2019/10/04 03:03:12.938 [error]: some exception happened
2019/10/04 03:53:35.595 [info]: there is a benign error in the code"

grep '\[error]:' <<< "$log"
# => 2019/10/04 03:03:12.938 [error]: some exception happened
#    2019/10/04 03:03:12.938 [error]: some exception happened
awk '$3 == "[error]:"' <<< "$log"
# => 2019/10/04 03:03:12.938 [error]: some exception happened
#    2019/10/04 03:03:12.938 [error]: some exception happened
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following pattern:

```
^.*\[error\]:.*$
```

For example:

```
grep "^.*\[error\]:.*$"
```

Comment: The `^.*` and `.*$` are doing nothing useful.

Comment: @EdMorton Are you related to Ed _Norton_?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers above. However, the issue is that the log contains color code for [error] and [info]. In the console it shows as [error] while in text it is actually [^[[31merror^[[0m]

To turn off the color code

```
cat xxx.log | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g'
```

To grep [error]:

```
cat xxx.log | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' | grep "\[error\]"
```